# How can I add a x.509 certificate to a Restful WCF service?

Tags: jquery, wcf, rest, ssl

I am a newbie with web services so please bear with me.I have a working WCF Restful Service hosted on localhost. I want to add security to my service.
I have come to know that I can add x.509 certificates to service and jquery client. Moreover , I have created the certificates using makecert.exe following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF#Introduction%20and%20Goal) tutorial.

I have added the certificates to the web.config file as depicted in the tutorial but service doed not ask for the certificate from the jquery client. It just responds with the data. I want service to respond only when it gets the certificate from the jquery client.

I can see the certificates listed under MMC console's trusted people panel.

Here is the configuration part of the service

```
     <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestDemo.RestDemo" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost/RestDemo/RestDemo.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost/RestDemo/RestDemo.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestDemo.IRestDemo" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>

        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="RestDemo.IRestDemo" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="web">

          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>

          </security>
        </binding>

      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="WCfServer"
              storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              storeName="My"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"
                          />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">

          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Even after adding the certificates in the web.config my service returns data tot he client. **I am running both service and client on the same machine**.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Install certificates
2. Configure a Port with an SSL certificate
3. Configure WCF service

For details see [SSL with Self-hosted WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service)